# Using counter with nth type

Tags: css, css-counter

Is it possible to have a counter with `nth-type` something like this:

```css
td:nth-of-type(counter(section)):before { 
     content: "Date"counter(section); 
     counter-increment: section;
}
```

Where counter is initialized as

```
#myTable  tr { 
    border: 1px solid #ccc; 
    counter-reset: section;counter-increment: section;
}
```

What I'm trying to do is this - check if `tr` has class iR and if it does, the structure looks like this:

```css
table.myTable td:nth-of-type(1):before { content: "Date"; }
table.myTable td:nth-of-type(2):before { content: "Fajr"; }
table.myTable td:nth-of-type(3):before { content: "Fr"; }
table.myTable td :nth-of-type(4):before { content: "Se"; }
table.myTable td:nth-of-type(5):before { content: "Dr"; }
table.myTable td:nth-of-type(6):before { content: " "; }
table.myTable td:nth-of-type(7):before { content: "A"; }
table.myTable td:nth-of-type(8):before { content: " "; }
table.myTable td:nth-of-type(9):before { content: "Mb"; }
table.myTable td:nth-of-type(10):before { content: " "; }
table.myTable td:nth-of-type(11):before { content: "I"; }
table.myTable td:nth-of-type(12):before { content: ""; }
```

If not it will be like this

```css
table.myTable td:nth-of-type(1):before { content: "Date"; }
table.myTable td:nth-of-type(2):before { content: "Fr"; }
table.myTable td :nth-of-type(3):before { content: "Se"; }
table.myTable td:nth-of-type(4):before { content: "Dr"; }
table.myTable td:nth-of-type(5):before { content: "A"; }
table.myTable td:nth-of-type(6):before { content: "Mb"; }
table.myTable td:nth-of-type(7):before { content: "I"; }
```

Here is jsfiddle what Im trying to do
https://jsfiddle.net/wj5gnafm/1/

Comment: what exactly do you want?

Comment: It is unclear what you trying to say. Please edit post and if possible give Code snippet/Fiddle.

Comment: `nth-of-type` can't take arguments like that. I assume you are trying to pass the counter's value to it.

Comment: like this https://jsfiddle.net/az4poa0d/

Comment: Why are you trying to set two `content` for the `:before`. I think a illustration of your expected output would be of more help than your code attempt for this case.

Comment: like this ? https://jsfiddle.net/az4poa0d/1/ with two different classes for `tr`

Comment: please check the update

Comment: I thought I understood your (now deleted) comment and posted an answer but the update to the code has got me confused again. There is no counter in there. What are you trying to do? Does my answer help?

Comment: Sorry about that but ya. I think your idea will work let try it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the fiddle that is now provided in question, you don't even need a `counter`. You should be able to achieve this just by using the class and negation selectors that I had mentioned in my original answer. Below is a sample snippet.

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid;
}
table tr.iRow td:nth-of-type(1):before {
  content: 'Date ';
}
table tr.iRow td:nth-of-type(2):before {
  content: 'Fr ';
}
table tr.iRow td:nth-of-type(3):before {
  content: '';
}
table tr.iRow td:nth-of-type(4):before {
  content: 'Se ';
}
table tr.iRow td:nth-of-type(5):before {
  content: 'Dr ';
}
table tr.iRow td:nth-of-type(6):before {
  content: '';
}
table tr.iRow td:nth-of-type(7):before {
  content: 'A ';
}
table tr.iRow td:nth-of-type(8):before {
  content: '';
}
table tr.iRow td:nth-of-type(9):before {
  content: 'Mb ';
}
table tr.iRow td:nth-of-type(10):before {
  content: '';
}
table tr.iRow td:nth-of-type(11):before {
  content: 'I ';
}
table tr.iRow td:nth-of-type(12):before {
  content: '';
}
table tr:not(.iRow) td:nth-of-type(1):before {
  content: 'Date ';
}
table tr:not(.iRow) td:nth-of-type(2):before {
  content: 'Fr ';
}
table tr:not(.iRow) td:nth-of-type(3):before {
  content: 'Se ';
}
table tr:not(.iRow) td:nth-of-type(4):before {
  content: 'Dr ';
}
table tr:not(.iRow) td:nth-of-type(5):before {
  content: 'A ';
}
table tr:not(.iRow) td:nth-of-type(6):before {
  content: 'Mb ';
}
table tr:not(.iRow) td:nth-of-type(7):before {
  content: 'I ';
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class='iRow'>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>D</td>
    <td>E</td>
    <td>F</td>
    <td>G</td>
    <td>H</td>
    <td>I</td>
    <td>J</td>
    <td>K</td>
    <td>L</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>D</td>
    <td>E</td>
    <td>E</td>
    <td>E</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

**Answer for original question:**

As I had mentioned in my comment to the question, you cannot pass the counter's value as argument to the `nth-of-type` (or any other `nth-*`) selectors.

You can achieve your expected output by doing the `counter-increment` only when the required class is present (by using class selector) and use `:not([classname])` to increment the other counter.

While displaying the value, make use of either the class or the  class-negation in the selector and then display the value as required. Below is a sample snippet.

```css
table {
  counter-reset: section, section-other;
}
table, tr, td {
  border: 1px solid;
}
table tr.iRow {
  counter-increment: section;
  background: sandybrown; /* just for distinction */
}
table .iRow td:nth-of-type(1):before {
  content: "Foo." counter(section)" ";
}
table .iRow td:nth-of-type(2):before {
  content: "Bar." counter(section)" ";
}
table .iRow td:nth-of-type(3):before {
  content: "Baz." counter(section)" ";
}
table tr:not(.iRow) {
  counter-increment: section-other;
  background: wheat; /* just for distinction */
}
table tr:not(.iRow) td:nth-of-type(1):before {
  content: "ooF." counter(section-other)" ";
}
table tr:not(.iRow) td:nth-of-type(2):before {
  content: "raB." counter(section-other)" ";
}
table tr:not(.iRow) td:nth-of-type(3):before {
  content: "zaB." counter(section-other)" ";
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class='iRow'>
    <td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='iRow'>
    <td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td>  
  </tr>
  <tr class='iRow'>
    <td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td>  
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td>  
  </tr>
  <tr class='iRow'>
    <td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td>  
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td>  
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td>  
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: please check the jsfiddle in question

Comment: @user5641155 I just did but that doesn't need any counter at all. I will add an answer without using counter.

Comment: @user5641155: Have a look at the first snippet in my answer. That should solve your problem.

Comment: WOW..true cant believe that didn't cross my mind Thank you buddy